# Java Selenium: cannot get any element after successful login

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium to login to website https://launch.stellar.org/#/login. but I can't get any element in new page.

here the code:

```
public class SeleniumProcessor {
public WebDriver driver;


public SeleniumProcessor() {
    this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

public void openUrl(String url) {
    driver.get(url);
}

public void login(String userName, String password) {
    WebElement userNameTxt = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    WebElement passwordTxt = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    userNameTxt.sendKeys(userName);
    passwordTxt.sendKeys(password);
    passwordTxt.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SeleniumProcessor login = new SeleniumProcessor();
    login.openUrl("https://launch.stellar.org/#/login");
    login.login("myusername", "mypassword");
    // login success but after that when I execute findElement function is always throw Exception like this
```

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector btn btn-default stellar-button ng-binding is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted
....

I also try using Explicit and Implicit Waits,... but didn't work, even print getCurrentURL() always is "https://launch.stellar.org/#/login". Does any one know the potential reason or solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an AngularJS based App getting around finding elements might be a bit of a hassle except if using Protractor otherwise you end up with Long Xpaths and CSS selectors.

Here's a snippet of your course refactored to work for me.
I noticed that you said you were using explicit wait, well it did worked for me...
My Advice is study the behavior of an app Manually and carefully before putting to automation.

```
 public class AutoTest{

public static WebDriver autoDriver;

public AutoTest(){

    autoDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    autoDriver.get("https://launch.stellar.org/#/login");

}

public void login(String username, String password) throws InterruptedException{

    autoDriver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
    autoDriver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    autoDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.='Log in']")).click();


}

public void faceBookStellar() throws InterruptedException{

    WebElement facebookButon = new WebDriverWait(autoDriver, 10)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[.='Receive your first stellars on us!']")));
    facebookButon.click();


}

public void quiteBrowser(){

    autoDriver.close();
    autoDriver.quit();
}

public static void main(String[]args) throws InterruptedException{

    AutoTest testObject = new AutoTest();
    testObject.login("autoStellarTester", "password");
    testObject.faceBookStellar();

}
```

}

Comment: first thank to your solution, it's work. But i still dont get why and where i wrong.
i use:
WebElement btn = (new WebDriverWait(login.driver, 15)).until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver d){
                return d.findElement(By.className("btn btn-default stellar-button ng-binding"));
            }
        });
btn.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

Comment: i need a favor, where i can learn syntax of parameter in By.xpath?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp
Also What you wrote in the comment is a Fluent Wait

Answer (score 0):

You write, that your login succeed. How do you know this?
I don't have an account for stellar.org, but if getCurrentUrl still delivers "https://launch.stellar.org/#/login", then I would suggest your login failed.
Have you tried `driver.getPageSource()`?

Also you receive an InvalidSelectorException. I guess the Exception tried to explain itself. Either your selector is wrong (maybe a forgotten close-bracket) or the selector doesn't result in a WebElement.
If you wan't help with your exception it might be target-aimed to post the selector which caused the exception.

Comment: because when i run project, firefox is opened and i can see it login succeed.

Comment: And when yuo are logged in manually, what is the current url? Maybe your code is faster than your browser. Have you tried waiting for an indicator, that firefox is ready with the login-procedure? Like waiting for the 'logout'-Button?